Unique "clique" of differences in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$
Are there absolute constants $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the following holds: For every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and every $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $\frac{\lvert A \rvert}{m} < \epsilon$ and with trivial stabilizer (i.e., for every $0\neq a \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, $A+a \neq A$), there are $d_1,\dots,d_N \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\lvert A \cap (A+d_1) \cap \dots \cap (A+d_N)\rvert = 1$?
I know that for $N=1$ (i.e., the existence of a unique difference) this is completely false, and $\epsilon$ should be in the order of magnitude of $\frac{\log_2m}{m}$. But I couldn't find any reference for this more general question.

Of course, sorry again @PeterMueller

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

For a random $A$ all such intersections have linear size with high probability, do not they?

@FedorPetrov What do you mean? Even for $N=1$, for each $d \neq 0$, the random variable $\lvert A \cap (A+d) \rvert $ has expectation $ \epsilon^2 $ (at least if the elements of $A$ are drawn i.i.d with probability $ \epsilon $, not sure if that's the thing to look at), but I'm asking for the minimum of all these $m-1$ random variables

expectation of $|A\cap (A+d)|$ is $\epsilon^2 m$, not $\epsilon^2$. This is linear in $m$. And the probability that it is less than, say, $\epsilon^3 m$, is exponentially small. The same for arbitrary fixed $N$.

@FedorPetrov Thanks! And sorry for the missing $m$

@FedorPetrov But why is it exponentially small? The variance of the size seems to be linear as well, no? (These things are pretty far from me, so I'm probably missing something very simple)

Let's consider the model when every element belongs to $A$ with probability $\epsilon$ independently of others. Then you may find $m/(N+1)^2$ disjoint subsets of the form ${x, x-d_1,x-d_2,\ldots, x-d_N}$. Each of them is contained in $A$ with probability $\epsilon^{N+1} $, and these events are independent, so the probability that at most one if them holds is exponentially small

Right, thanks! So it's not about linear size, but this is enough.

A simple probabilistic argument shows that this is false, see @FedorPetrov 's comments.

There is no such pair of $\epsilon$ and $N$: Set $m=k^2$ with $k$ big enough, $G=\mathbb Z/k^2\mathbb Z$ and $H=k\mathbb Z/k^2\mathbb Z$. With $A=H\setminus\{0\}$ we have
\begin{equation}
(A+x)\cap(A+y)=H\setminus\{x, y\}
\end{equation}
for all $x,y\in H$.
Now suppose that $A\cap(A+d_1)\cap\cdots\cap(A+d_N)$ has size $1$. Then in particular this intersection is not empty, hence $d_i\in H$ for all $i$. But then every element from $H\setminus\{0,d_1,\ldots,d_N\}$ is in this intersection too, a contradiction once $\lvert H\rvert=k\ge N+3$.

A similar argument shows that if we let $N$ and $\epsilon$ depend on $m$, the result cannot hold unless $(N+2)/\epsilon\ge m$ or so.

Thanks! It seems I have been careless when trying to allow any $m$ instead of only primes.
